# access linkopts in rule

Tags: bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I have declared a simple

cc_binary(
`name = "hello_world", srcs = ["hello_world.cpp"], linkopts = [ "-nostdlib",`
])

I would like to access linkopts so that I can show some error message .
I have also implemented toolchain

def _impl(ctx):

```
print(ctx.attr.link_flags)
```

but I do not see nostdlib in list of flags.

How do I access linkopts flags in bzl file?
Appreciate if someone could help me.

I would like to access linkopts so that I can show some error message.
but I do not see nostdlib in list of flags.